# Codeigniter Sort

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$data['reg'] = $this->register->registerAcc($schoolID); 
$data['upd'] =$this->register->UpdateAcc($schoolID); 
$data['sus'] =$this->register->suspendAcc($schoolID);
$this->load->view('account/accountInfo',$data);
```

This is my code that consist of update,register,and suspend. every function have their own "date/time"

Every end of the function have this code:

> $this->db->order_by('register_Date','DESC'); 
>   every function have it own date, example register_Date , updateAcc_Date

But i have a problem , when i show in the page the list will go from

```
Date           Function       UserName
05-09-2019  Register    Tom
04-09-2019  Register    Bors
01-09-2019  Register    Berry
03-09-2019  Update      Laxy    
05-09-2019  Suspend     Loi
```

What I wanted is

```
Date           Function       UserName
05-09-2019  Register    Tom
05-09-2019  Suspend     Loi
04-09-2019  Register    Bors
03-09-2019  Update      Laxy    
01-09-2019  Register    Berry
```

below is my model

```
public function registerAcc($schoolID){
 $this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('registerdata');
$this->db->where('school_ID',$schoolID);
$this->db->order_by('registerDate','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $result = $query->result();
}

public function UpdateAcc($schoolID){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('UserUpdateLog');
$this->db->where('school_ID',$schoolID);
$this->db->order_by('UpdateDate','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $result = $query->result();
}

public function suspendAcc($schoolID){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('SuspendedData');
$this->db->where('school_ID',$schoolID);
$this->db->order_by('SuspendDate','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $result = $query->result();
}
```

My View

```
<thead style="width:300px;">
<th>Date</th>
<th>Function</th>
<th>UserName</th>
</thead>
<?php
foreach ($reg as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td ><?php echo $row->registerDate;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->registerStatus></td>
<td><?php echo $row->registerUserName></td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($upd as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td ><?php echo $row->UpdateDate;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->UpdateStatus></td>
<td><?php echo $row->UpdateUserName></td>
</tr>
<
?php
foreach ($sus as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td ><?php echo $row->SuspendDate;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->SuspendStatus></td>
<td><?php echo $row->SuspendUserName></td>
</tr>
```

Please note that: Consist of 3 different table and set it into $data

But when in view it will able to sort by DESC but it will sort according to "REGISTER" ,"UPDATE" and "SUSPEND" , i want that it able to mix together and sort

Comment: you can use multiple field order.

Comment: i do , the answer help , but not on my case . the method works

Comment: post your model code of this 3 functions (`registerAcc`, `UpdateAcc`, `suspendAcc`)

Comment: Are all functions querying 3 different tables??

Comment: @MohammedShafeek yeah, 3 different table

Comment: Same column structure?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek no , different structure.

Comment: But you returned same columns in your expected results..why?

Comment: Date, function, username..these three right?

Comment: oh , the "date, function,username"  is table name for (view)

Comment: It's better to show table schema..so that you could get all in single query

Comment: but it different table , now the problem right now is that when show it show "register (all row)" then "update (all row)" then "suspend (all row)"

Comment: so it impossible to fix it via view page ?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek added code for view page

Comment: is registerDateTime and registerDate are different columns???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198916/discussion-between-xaxacodess-and-mohammed-shafeek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate the follwing query in your CI model and will get all data in single function.
Instead of 3, you can loop the result array in view only once.

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    a1.registerDate AS dt,
    a1.registerStatus AS st,
    a1.registerUserName AS nm 
  FROM
    registerdata AS a1 
  WHERE a1.school_ID = '$schoolID' 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    a2.UpdateDate,
    a2.UpdateStatus,
    a2.UpdateUserName 
  FROM
    UserUpdateLog AS a2 
  WHERE a2.school_ID = '$schoolID' 
  UNION
  SELECT 
    a3.SuspendDate,
    a3.SuspendStatus,
    a3.SuspendUserName 
  FROM
    SuspendedData AS a3 
  WHERE a3.school_ID = '$schoolID') AS a 
ORDER BY a.dt DESC ;
```